# I have a problem with this query in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with this table in Postgres, it give me this error:

> ERROR:  cannot use subquery in check constraint
>   LINE 66:  check(Artista in(Select ID_Artista

```
create table DirigeF(
    Artista int references Artista(ID_Artista) on delete cascade,
    Film int references Film(ID_Contenuto) on delete cascade,
    check(Artista in(Select ID_Artista
                    from Artista
                    where tipologia='REGISTA'or'AR')),
    constraint DirigeF_PK primary key(Artista, Film)
);
```

I want to check that Artista in table DirigeF has tipologia='REGISTA' from another table.

Comment: You cannot look beyond current row in a CHECK constraint.

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, you cannot do this with a check constraint.  One option is a trigger.  Another is a foreign key constraint -- but that needs to be carefully arranged.

First you need a column that indicates whether the type in `Artista` is "REGISTA" or "AR".  That would be:

```
alter table artista add is_regista_ar bool generated always as 
    (tipologia in ('REGISTA', 'AR'));
```

Then create a unique constraint or index:

```
alter table artista add unq_artista_tipologia_id
    unique (is_regista_ar, id_artista)
```

Note:  This requires Postgres 12+.  But something similar can be done in earlier versions.

Then, add a boolean column to your table that is always `true`:

```
create table DirigeF (
    Artista int references Artista(ID_Artista) on delete cascade,
    Film int references Film(ID_Contenuto) on delete cascade,
    is_regista_ar bool generated always as true,
    constraint fk_artista_tipo_artista foreign key (is_regista_ar, Artista) references Artista(is_regista_ar, ID_Artista),
    constraint DirigeF_PK primary key (Artista, Film)
);
```